# Unable to open Eclipse Marketplace from Eclipse Neon on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-marketplace

I recently installed Neon on my Ubuntu machine. There is no problem with the IDE but I am unable to open the Marketplace as I want to install `Spring Suite and jHipster`.

The error trace is below:

```
Unexpected exception: org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file /home/interview/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1522219762532.profile.gz of length 0 failed to load properly
org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file /home/interview/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1522219762532.profile.gz of length 0 failed to load properly
org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file /home/interview/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1522219762532.profile.gz of length 0 failed to load properly
org.eclipse.oomph.util.IORuntimeException: The file /home/interview/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.6.3_1473617060_linux_gtk_x86_64/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.jee.profile/1522219762532.profile.gz of length 0 failed to load properly
```

Please tell me what the problem could be. I don't know if this is a duplicate. If it is please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't know what the problem was but it looks like it was a problem with the server which hosts the Eclipse Marketplace. The problem solved itself. To get rid of the problem permanently, delete the dependencies in the .eclipse folder. Solved my problem completely

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error when trying to install php tools on Eclipse Neon.
I just deleted the profile.gz file which appeared in the error message, and restarted Eclipse.
now installation works like a charm :)

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue when installing the C/C++ editor for eclipse through the marketplace. I initially installed the editor but closed eclipse before it could fully install. I think this caused the problem.

What I did was uninstall my entire ".eclipse" file system and then reinstall eclipse so that I could start fresh.

Just uninstalling the dependencies likely works for most people, but for some reason mine didn't. I was using the Virtual Box "Ubuntu" VM.